# Render output for iPad and smart TVs

Tags: video, file-format

I am a newbie so please be gentle.... 
I am trying to edit large MP4 family videos (a couple are mpv files).  I have tried multiple options for my output files ( as I said I don't really know what I am doing :-) )
None of the output files I have created can be read by my iPad or my Panasonic smart tv.
If I could output as MP4 then I know they are playable. I am using the windows 7 version.
Anyone able to provide advice? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this relate to Blender itself ? :)

Comment: Selecting MPEG as the output format, MPEG-4 encoding format, and H.264 as the video codec work? That should give you a fairly standard mp4.

Comment: I had similar (and other) problems with Blender's Mp4.  My solution/workaround was to render or place the external video into the VSE and render to H264 AVI, then export that to a non-expensive product called Vidopad by NCH software.  

Place the clip into Vpad's work area and export that as an mp4 at whatever dimension and resolution you like, or - choose from it's export list for iPhone and other devices.  Both my Panasonic TV's, Windows Media player, plus a stand alone external player all play the mp4's without problems